# Check if textbox contains specific decimal numbers

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm doing a school project but we weren't really taught about complex parts like this, so I'm hoping someone can help me.

I want my program to check whether my textbox contains 0.1-0.4 decimal numbers when I click a button. If yes, a message box will show that 0.5 or any half number must be entered. But, if the textbox contains 0.6-0.9, the message box will say to enter a whole number.

I know the message box part, I just don't know how to check those specific decimal numbers in the textbox. And also, if the textbox contain a whole number or a half number (.5), it will proceed to do what is stated.

```
If (Textbox1=0.1-0.4) Then
MsgBox("Enter a half number.")
ElseIf (TextBox1=0.6-0.9) Then
MsgBox("Enter a whole number.")
ElseIf (TextBox1=Half Number or TextBox1=Whole Number) Then
MsgBox("Transaction complete.")
End If
```

Comment: What you'd want to do, is to sanitize the textbox to make sure a valid number/decimal has been inputted, then you'd want to parse the entry to a decimal, do some if statements to make sure the number lies between the numbers you've stated before and produce a MessageBox Dialog when it reaches the condition(s).

Comment: What about `0.01`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement) statement once you have converted the TextBox's Text to a numeric value:

```
Sub CheckDecimals(number As String)

    If IsNumeric(number) Then

        ' Convert number to Single
        Dim singleNumber As Single = CSng(number)

        ' Use Mod to get fraction only
        Dim modNumber As Single = singleNumber Mod 1

        Select Case modNumber
            Case 0, 0.5
                MsgBox("Transaction complete.")
            Case Is < 0.5
                MsgBox("Enter a half number.")
            Case Is > 0.5
                MsgBox("Enter a whole number.")
        End Select

    Else
        MsgBox("Please enter a number.")
    End If

End Sub
```

In your button Click event handler, use:

```
CheckDecimals(TextBox1.Text)
```

Comment: Hello! It might take a few days before I can try this but thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Sorry for the very late response! It worked, thank you so much!